# How can I except escape sequences?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I loaded a file, '\n' was converted to '\\n' automatically.
Can I get raw strings? Or do you have any idea?

setting.yaml:

```
before : '\n'
after  : ''
```

source:

```
with open(r"C:\setting.yaml", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as text:
    print(text)
    raw_yml = yaml.load(text)
    before = raw_yml.get("before")  # '\\n'
    after = raw_yml.get("after")    # ''

    sample_str = "\n\n\txxxx\n\n"
    result = sample_str.replace(before, after)

    # I want to get "\txxxx", but "\n\n\txxxx\n\n" was printed.
    print(result)
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the file as described in the [yaml documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#LoadingYAML)?

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean `yaml.load("before : '\n'")`? This code is a sample. Actually I should load several setting yaml files that someone makes.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood. If you want to remove newline `\n` from a string you could use `result = sample_str.strip('\n')` . But I'm not sure if that is what you are asking about.